# Clojure priority-map

Tags: clojure

I have the following,

```
(let [t (priority-map-by (comparator (fn [[f1 _] [f2 _]]
                                       (< f1 f2)))
                         :b [8 [2 1]])]

  (assoc t :c [8 [2 3]]))
```

for some reason the associated item :c is modified after it is added to the map what I get is,

```
{:c [8 [2 1]], :b [8 [2 1]]}
```

what I expect is,

```
{:c [8 [2 3]], :b [8 [2 1]]}
```

am I missing something obvious why is the items value is modified? or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what I wanted by not using a comparator and returning -1 0 1 depending on the cond,

```
(let [t (priority-map-by (fn [x y]
                             (if (= x y)
                               0
                               (let [[f1 _] x
                                     [f2 _] y]
                                 (if (< f1 f2) -1 1))))

                         :b [8 [2 1]])]

  (assoc t :c [8 [2 3]]))
```

that gives me what I want,

```
{:b [8 [2 1]], :c [8 [2 3]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/priority_map.clj) for `priority-map-by`, it appears to be based on `sorted-map-by`, which holds that keys that compare the same are the same. For example:

```
(sorted-map-by (fn [[a] [b]] (< a b)) [1 2] :foo [1 3] :bar)
=> {[1 2] :bar}
```

This also holds true for `sorted-set-by`:

```
(sorted-set-by (fn [[a] [b]] (< a b)) [1 2] [1 3] [3 4])
=> #{[1 2] [3 4]}
```

Whether that's intended behavior for `priority-map-by`, you'd have to ask the author. I think it's reasonable.